# how to stop the timed background task gracefully

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core

I am trying a stop the timed background task gracefully, and code I am trying with is

```
public Task StopAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        //to stop timer from making any further calls to ProcessFailures
        _timer?.Change(Timeout.Infinite, 0);

        bool isGracefullStopStarted = false;
        while (_isProcessing)
        {
            if (!isGracefullStopStarted)
            {
                string text =string.Format("worker service stopping gracefully at : {0}", DateTimeOffset.Now);
                System.IO.File.WriteAllText(@"C:\PCF\WriteText\txt.txt", text);
            }
            isGracefullStopStarted = true;
        }
        string text1 = string.Format("worker service stopped at : {0}", DateTimeOffset.Now);
        System.IO.File.WriteAllText(@"C:\PCF\WriteText\txt.txt", text1);
    }
```

_isProcessing will be false when execution of ongoing job is completed(Task.Delay(20000)). So I expect while loop to run until processing is complete however, when I debug control comes to while loop only once and service stops after that. what am I not understanding here?

Comment: 1: your while loop will cause 100% cpu. 2. do you await the Task.Delay(20000)? 3. The debugger will get to the while loop only once, but the code inside it should be executed repeatedly. When do you debug, do you check the value of _isProcessing?

Comment: @OguzOzgul, 1, Yes that is something I definitely have to remove. 2. yes I do await Task.Delay(20000). 3. Yes I am trying to check the value of _isProcessing while debugging, but I just noticed service is stopping 2-3 seconds after hitting stopasync, no matter where the control is.

Comment: Can you please share the code where you are calling StopAsync and Task.Delay(20000)?